# unable to install capybara-webkit in centos 8

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install capybara, on my ruby 2.7.3 system, and it's failing.

I appear to not be able to look at the output and see the magic words `Command 'qmake ' not available`

my output:

```
gem install capybara-webkit
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.15.1
/var/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin/ruby -I /var/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20210604-1512733-c8fw23.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/var/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-gl-dir
        --without-gl-dir
        --with-gl-include
        --without-gl-include=${gl-dir}/include
        --with-gl-lib
        --without-gl-lib=${gl-dir}/lib
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
Command 'qmake ' not available

extconf failed, exit code 1



Gem files will remain installed in /var/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/capybara-webkit-1.15.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/capybara-webkit-1.15.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: can you install `qmake` on your system?

Comment: If I run the following command -  whereis qmake
response =qmake: /usr/bin/qmake  and in /usr/lib64/qt5/bin in these path qmake file is present. So any specific command to check qmake is installed or not ?

Comment: in that case, I'd suggest that you look at `/var/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/capybara-webkit-1.15.1/gem_make.out` and see if there is a more specific error in there that hasn't been output

Comment: Hey Jad, I have checked but same error is printed in that file.

Comment: there might be a little more context to it.  can you edit your question and add in the section of the file that includes the error?

Comment: hey jad it is same as in above mention.

Comment: it doesn't quite make sense, if you have the qmake program, but it can't find it.  can you try compiling the gem manually, from the directory?

Comment: hey jad, I try compiling gem manually still got the same error.

Comment: if you try just `qmake` on it's own, what output do you get?

Comment: cmd - qmake
response = -bash: qmake: command not found
cmd -  whereis qmake
response - qmake: /usr/bin/qmake
cmd -  which qmake
/usr/bin/which: no qmake in (/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3@global/bin:/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/home/user/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/user/.rvm/bin)

Comment: that seems like the problem.  can you try the full path `/usr/bin/qmake` and see if the response is different? if it isn't then you'll need to see if you can reinstall `qmake`